# Error 3002 in EF after update model of a view

Tags: sql, entity-framework, view, updatemodel

We use EF 3.5, Database first.
After I have updated my view, I received next error message:

> Error 1   Error 3002: Problem in Mapping Fragment starting at line 866:
>   Potential runtime violation of table vPendingOrders's keys
>   (vPendingOrders.AccountId, vPendingOrders.AccountName,
>   vPendingOrders.ApplicationModeTypeId,
>   vPendingOrders.CampaignWorkflowId, vPendingOrders.EndDate,
>   vPendingOrders.HiddenInGeneralList, vPendingOrders.HiddenInOwnerList,
>   vPendingOrders.InstanceId, vPendingOrders.OrgId,
>   vPendingOrders.StartDate, vPendingOrders.TotalBudget): Columns
>   (vPendingOrders.CampaignWorkflowId, vPendingOrders.InstanceId,
>   vPendingOrders.OrgId, vPendingOrders.AccountId,
>   vPendingOrders.AccountName, vPendingOrders.TotalBudget,
>   vPendingOrders.StartDate, vPendingOrders.EndDate,
>   vPendingOrders.HiddenInGeneralList, vPendingOrders.HiddenInOwnerList,
>   vPendingOrders.ApplicationModeTypeId) are mapped to EntitySet
>   vPendingOrders's properties (vPendingOrders.CampaignWorkflowId,
>   vPendingOrders.InstanceId, vPendingOrders.OrgId,
>   vPendingOrders.AccountId, vPendingOrders.AccountName,
>   vPendingOrders.TotalBudget, vPendingOrders.StartDate,
>   vPendingOrders.EndDate, vPendingOrders.HiddenInGeneralList,
>   vPendingOrders.HiddenInOwnerList,
>   vPendingOrders.ApplicationModeTypeId) on the conceptual side but they
>   do not form the EntitySet's key properties (vPendingOrders.AccountId,
>   vPendingOrders.AccountName, vPendingOrders.ApplicationModeTypeId,
>   vPendingOrders.CampaignWorkflowId, vPendingOrders.EndDate,
>   vPendingOrders.HiddenInGeneralList, vPendingOrders.HiddenInOwnerList,
>   vPendingOrders.InstanceId, vPendingOrders.OrgId,
>   vPendingOrders.SalesRep, vPendingOrders.StartDate,
>   vPendingOrders.TotalBudget).

As you see there is no my new fileds FullName, Email and ContactId

The view looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vPendingOrders]
AS
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT wf.CampaignWorkflow.CampaignWorkflowId, wf.CampaignWorkflow.InstanceId, dbo.vCampaigns.OrgId, wf.CampaignWorkflow.CampaignId, 
                  dbo.vCampaigns.AccountId, wf.CampaignWorkflow.HasProposalReview, wf.CampaignWorkflow.HasMediaReview, wf.CampaignWorkflow.HasTraffickingEnabled, 
                  dbo.vCampaigns.AccountName, wf.CampaignWorkflow.HasAuthorizedCreditCard, wf.CampaignWorkflow.HasAppliedForCredit, wf.CampaignWorkflow.HasDrops, 
                  dbo.vCampaigns.TotalBudget, wf.CampaignWorkflow.StateMessage, dbo.vCampaigns.StartDate, dbo.vCampaigns.EndDate, dbo.vCampaigns.OwnerId, 
                  dbo.vCampaigns.OwnerType, dbo.vCampaigns.HiddenInGeneralList, dbo.vCampaigns.HiddenInOwnerList, wf.CampaignWorkflow.ApplicationModeTypeId, 
                  dbo.vCampaigns.SalesRep, dbo.vCampaigns.AdvertiserName,
                   --  new values
                   dbo.vCampaigns.FullName, dbo.vCampaigns.Email, dbo.vCampaigns.ContactId
FROM         wf.CampaignWorkflow INNER JOIN
                  dbo.vCampaigns ON wf.CampaignWorkflow.CampaignId = dbo.vCampaigns.CampaignId
ORDER BY wf.CampaignWorkflow.CampaignWorkflowId DESC
```

Also I just tried to add just an existing column as alias(duplicate): dbo.vCampaigns.AdvertiserName
The result for next 24-th column\property is the same - an error 3002

In properties of that field  EntityKey is false and Nullable is true.

I also add here anothe view, from which I take my values:

```
    SELECT     cam.Campaign.CampaignId, cam.Campaign.OrgId, cam.Campaign.OwnerId,    cam.Campaign.AccountId, 
   -- here they are
   cam.Campaign.ContactId, SalesRep.FullName, SalesRep.Email, 
 cam.Campaign.AgencyId, 
                          cam.Campaign.CampaignName, Advertiser.AccountName, Agency.AccountName AS AgencyName, cam.CampaignStatus.Code AS Type, 
                          cam.Campaign.OwnerType, cam.Campaign.StartDate, cam.Campaign.EndDate, dbo.fnGetCampaignRunStatus(cam.Campaign.CampaignId, NULL) 
                          AS Status, wf.CampaignWorkflow.StateMessage, wf.CampaignWorkflow.CampaignWorkflowId, cam.Campaign.TotalBudget, 
                          cam.Campaign.HiddenInGeneralList, cam.Campaign.HiddenInOwnerList, cam.Campaign.Note, 
                          CASE WHEN wf.CampaignWorkflow.ApplicationModeTypeId = 2 THEN CASE WHEN SalesRep.ContactId IS NULL 
                          THEN Owner.FullName ELSE SalesRep.FullName END ELSE CASE WHEN SalesRep.ContactId IS NULL 
                          THEN 'N/A' ELSE SalesRep.FullName END END AS SalesRep, CASE WHEN wf.CampaignWorkflow.ApplicationModeTypeId IS NULL 
                          THEN 1 ELSE wf.CampaignWorkflow.ApplicationModeTypeId END AS ApplicationModeTypeId, 
                          con.CustomListItem.CustomListItemName AS AdvertiserName, cam.Campaign.ClientOrderId
    FROM         cam.Campaign INNER JOIN
                          org.Account AS Advertiser ON cam.Campaign.AccountId = Advertiser.AccountId INNER JOIN
                          cam.CampaignStatus ON cam.Campaign.CampaignStatusId = cam.CampaignStatus.CampaignStatusId INNER JOIN
                          con.Contact AS Owner ON cam.Campaign.OwnerId = Owner.ContactId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          con.CustomListItem ON cam.Campaign.AdvertiserId = con.CustomListItem.CustomListItemId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          wf.CampaignWorkflow ON cam.Campaign.CampaignId = wf.CampaignWorkflow.CampaignId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          org.Account AS Agency ON cam.Campaign.AgencyId = Agency.AccountId AND cam.Campaign.AgencyId = Agency.AccountId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          con.Contact AS SalesRep ON cam.Campaign.SalesRepId = SalesRep.ContactId
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was in strange update result of EF model update operation. SaleRep in view (database) is still a key, but in model view it was deleted(automatically) from set of keys. But not everywhere or something else...
So the solution - Set Entity Key to False and Nullable to True not for new fields, But for SalesRep